# Can anyone tell me if this is legit WW2 Nazi ring?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, identification

My little ten year old brother found a rusted can that had this 925 prooved silver ring  in it, with a small note/letter that only said some numbers, which he said looked like born/died dates. He only brought the ring home, so we actually did not see the note.

The can was found in a place that just had an old building torn down. The place was an old and abandoned building right next to a railway station and the tracks in a small city called [Tukums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukums). Our home is not far from the railway station, so kids used to hang around there.

It definitely looks like a ring from WW2, when Nazis occupied Latvia for some years.
The German Nazi occupation of Latvia happened from 1941–1945. Plus, during the occupation, the Germans looked to recruit Latvian units for their armies.

Does anyone know if this ring is actually from that period?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm no expert but from the size and style I'd guess that this was post-war - the genuine German death's head rings were smaller.

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, Linda! How do you know the silver content, where is that letter, how do you associate this with Latvia (where in the world was that torn down building), is that really a ring (that fit one of your fingers)? What do you mean with "evidence"? Please [edit] any additional info into the question.

Comment: Guys, ok, the last comment on a google search just convinced me. Thanks for quick help.

Answer (score 16):

Your ring looks just like the ring a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1536&bih=750&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=n7S8XPL-FqPi0gL_ppKICA&q=iron%20cross%20soldier%20skull%20ring&oq=iron%20cross%20soldier%20skull%20ring&gs_l=img.12...22294.22294..25767...0.0..0.97.97.1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.ufPYyfO3DQE#imgrc=fZN-ga0oOt2V5M:) shows as ***Biker*** Sterling Silver Jewelry for Men.

[image]

Note the symbol displayed on the ring is not strictly a Nazi symbol, but the [Iron Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Cross) or perhaps a [Cross Pattee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_patt%C3%A9e), which predate the Nazi regime. An article discussing the Iron Cross's association with biker culture can be read [here](https://slmotorcycles.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/bikers-and-the-iron-cross/).

Below you can compare to the actual [Death's Head Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Ehrenring) worn by the SS.

[image]

Comment: Yo. That was surprisingly straightforward. Perhaps spell out conclusions from this find, or compare (verbally) differences with actual pre45 jewelry?